# How to get Mifare SmartMX protocol

Tags: protocols, smartcard, mifare

I want to ask about Mifare SmartMX.

1. How to get Mifare SmartMX protocol?
2. What Mifare Reader/Writer type which support for Mifare SmartMX card?
3. Is [MIFARE SDK Advanced](https://www.mifare.net/en/products/tools/mifare-sdk/mifare-sdk-advanced/) support for Mifare SmartMX card?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To set some things straight:

- Mifare denotes a family of contactless protocols by NXP (variants are classic, DESfire...)
- SmartMx is a family of microprocessor cards from NXP; there are variants purely contactbased as well as dual-interface ones. The latter ones may also support ISO 14443 type A or a MIFARE classic protocol for legacy applications.

So the answers are:

1. This does not exist
2. Assumed you have the appropriate chip: any MIFARE reader
3. Under same condition as 2: yes

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.